# Soundcloud: preparing multiple tracks for streaming?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

After [Soundcloud: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined when trying to play the song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385015/) was resolved (thanks again) I'm going to do the next - I want to prepare multiple SM2 instances for playing multiple tracks on demand.

Here's the code (non-compiled CoffeeScript for readability this time, the whole jsbin can be seen here http://jsbin.com/ejapin/edit#javascript,html)

```
$ ->
    SOUNDCLOUD_ID = '6d5064768cc29c71e1f66691f435589a'
    PLAYLIST_ID = '1768866'
    SC.initialize client_id: SOUNDCLOUD_ID

    tracks = []
    tracks_total = 0

    tracks_ready = ->
        for track in tracks
          console.log track
          track.play()

    SC.get '/playlists/' + PLAYLIST_ID, (pl) ->
        tracks_total = pl.tracks.length
        for track in pl.tracks
            console.log "Fetching"
            SC.stream "/tracks/#{track.id}", {}, (sound) ->
                tracks.push sound
                console.log "+ Fetched #{tracks.length}"
                if tracks.length == tracks_total
                    tracks_ready()
```

I see Fetching logged 11 times and I also see SM2's swf to be requested the same number of times.

But the callback is called for the (*updated*) **LAST** track only (yet the sound is playing OK for it).

UPD: btw, it also inserts the SM2 js multiple times which looks like an issue

Comment: heh, for readability, I'd have preferred the compiled version. :p

Comment: @nickf see the link to jsbin for the compiled code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the SC JS SDK causing this.
We've deployed a fix today that should fix this.
Thanks for reporting this! Please let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: well, just got some time to check it. much better - all the tracks load... uninitialised (readyState==0); the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cTeU2/

Comment: you can pass the soundmanager option autoLoad if you want to preload the audio: 
 SC.stream("/tracks/" + track.id, {autoLoad: true}, track_loaded(i));

Comment: thanks, but the same result here - in tracks_ready method all readyState's are zeroes

Comment: Looks like you're passing autoLoad: true to SC.get, not SC.stream.